# BoxCollider2D bounds.Contain(somePoint) works not as expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I have a little problem with `BoxCollider2D`. When I do this:

```
bool someBool = someBounds.Contains(somePoint);
```

I get expected result when the body has no rotation like on the picture 1. (red area is where somePoint makes someBool true)
And when the body is rotated, somePoint makes someBool true everywhere inside the red area(picture 2). I don't want this kind of behaviour. I want point to return true inside the green area(picture 3).

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to rotate the red box with the green?

Comment: the red box doesn't exist, it is just to show area where bounds contain somePoint.

Comment: The Unity BocXollider2D has a transform property. So u need to apply the same transformation to the collider as to the object. This is what I would try first. Not 100% sure.

Comment: How are you rotating this Body? You need to make sure that you are rotating the BoxCollider2D too, and not expanding it.

Comment: The `BoxCollider2D` component belongs to the same `GameObject` of that body that you are rotating?

Comment: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/rotating-sprite-does-not-rotate-collider.212327/ . Basically, rotate over 'z' only as well as do not flip over the body (as it's 2D). You can also try to set rigidbody to 'fixed'. If it doesn't help, use poly collider instead of 2D collider, but as the bug related to this issue dates back to 2006, hopefully it was not re-introduced so you won't need this workaround.

Comment: It is possible than the object image are a square? In the left up corner of your Scene View select Shaded Wireframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish your goal, use `BoxCollider2D.OverlapPoint` like this:

```
bool overlaps = myBoxCollider2D.OverlapPoint (somePoint);
```

The `bounds` of a `BoxCollider2D` assume that the object is an AABB - "axis-aligned bounding box", meaning it is not rotated and is aligned like in picture 1. So, really your pictures 1 and 2 prove this.

Source: If you go to the [BoxCollider2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BoxCollider2D.html) documentation, click on [Bounds](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D-bounds.html), then click on the [Bounds](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.html) class, you will see the details of what the bounds refer to.